# how do I get python to recognize modules installed in virtual environment?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtual-environment

I'm having trouble getting python in vs code to work properly. There were problems for a while (i dove right in with a workspace folder) so I decided to set up everything from scratch by starting a new project/workspace folder.

so far I've been having a few issues. The latest is this: despite creative a virtual environment as instructed on the vs code website, I can't get python to recognize that I've already installed the modules I want to use.

How do I fix this? (please see attached picture.

[towards the bottom you can see that the virtual environment already has matplotlib, but python wouldn't recognize the module anyway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3KNc.png)

Comment: Your python code is not actually running through your virtual environment in that picture. It's using the base install of python. Look for how to set vscode python environment.

Comment: With your virtual environment activated, just call `python.exe` without any full path. This way you should call the python executable from within your virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your virtual environment (e.g I used venv module to create a virtual env called `TEST` : `$python3 -m venv TEST`
2. From VS code go to `Command Palette` and type `Python: Select Interpreter`

[image]

And then you can choose the location of the desired interpreter (in my case the one from `TEST` virtual environment

[image]

3. You can always test your virtual environment from the terminal, e.g `TEST` env

Bash

[image: From Bash]

From Cmd/Powershell normally you should run:

```
TEST\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried that but it didn't work. I still get the same error. I'm now trying to delete all instances of python from my system and start over with visualstudio or even switching to pycharm. Not sure where to go from here.